# Jquery .keyup, .keypress and .keydown: problems with timing (and advices on refactoring the code)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a form in which the user can set the width and the height of an iframe and then those values are used to build a string to embed on a web page.

The idea is that once the user has filled the input, the string automatically updates itself with the new inserted values.

But it seems the string is updated not in timing: it seems it losts the last "key press".

Here is the code I've wrote

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    
        $('iframe#WidgetContent').width(300);
    
        // Get the value of the input width box
        $( 'form #WidgetConfigurator_width' ).keyup(function() {
    
            var width=parseInt( $(this).val());
    
            if ( width < 180 ) {
                width = 180;
            }
    
            if ( width > 500 ) {
                width = 500;
            }
    
            $('iframe#WidgetContent').width(width);
    
            getEmbeddableCode();
        });
    });
    
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    
        $('iframe#WidgetContent').height(500);
    
        // Get the value of the input width box
        $( 'form #WidgetConfigurator_height' ).keypress(function() {
    
            var height=parseInt( $(this).val());
    
            if ( height < 70 ) {
                height = 70;
            }
    
            $('iframe#WidgetContent').height(height);
    
            getEmbeddableCode();
        });
    });
    
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        window.getEmbeddableCode = function() {
            var iframe     = $('iframe#WidgetContent');
            var height     = iframe.height();
            var width      = iframe.width();
            var host       = $(location).attr('protocol') + '//' + $(location).attr('hostname');
    
            var code = '<iframe id="WidgetContent" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/widget/1/" frameborder="0" height="' + height + '" width="' + width + '"></iframe>';
    
            $('#getEmbeddableCode').html(code);
        };
    });
    
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if ( '' === $( '#getEmbeddableCode' ).val() ) {
            getEmbeddableCode();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="WidgetConfigurator" method="post" id="WidgetConfigurator">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="WidgetConfigurator_width">Width widget</label>
        <input type="text" id="WidgetConfigurator_width" name="WidgetConfigurator[width]" class="form-control" placeholder="Da un minimo 180 a un massimo di 500">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="WidgetConfigurator_height">Height widget</label>
        <input type="text" id="WidgetConfigurator_height" name="WidgetConfigurator[height]" class="form-control" placeholder="Minimo 70">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="getEmbeddableCode">Clicca e il codice si copierà automaticamente</label>
        <textarea id="getEmbeddableCode" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>

<iframe id="WidgetContent" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/widget/1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Anyway, the problem is that if i wrote, for example, 200 in Width `input` the value in the textarea is never 200 but something else (sometimes is 192, other times is 180, other times another value: it seems to be a random number).
Once I start to write the value in the Height `input`, the correct value is taken from the Width one, but the same thing happens at the same time for the Height value: it is never the one i write in the `input`.

I think there is something I'm not considering with timings, but, since this is the very first script I write with Jquery I'm sure there is something I'm missing.

Any advices? Thank you!

PS
As this is my first very practical approach to Jquery, I'd like to receive also feedback s about refact the code that I think is now a little bit messy. If someone can help me understand how to better structure the code it will be very helpful!

Comment: I may or may not answer it successfully, but this question is making me laugh. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can make your life a lot easier by using a library, rather than doing it from scratch with jQuery. This looks like a perfect use case for Vue.js.

Comment: is there a reason for that ... type of code? why are you calling `ready()`  5 times and why do you want to listen to a key events on an input when with jquery you could just use `change()` (https://api.jquery.com/change/)? You should dig a bit deeper in documentations before using stuff.

Comment: @toddmo, I'm pleased you are laughing, but a real answer maybe more helpful to make me learn ;)

Comment: @hashchange thank you: I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Kryptik, I'm calling it 5 times because... I'm not practic with Jquery and Js and this is my very first script and thought this way the code is better organized. Should I have to put all in one ready() call? Anyway I will try to use change() (that I've used in another... Ready()  ). Yes read the docs but this is the time of make my hands dirty (and it seems the code too!)

Comment: @Aerendir, with the help of these comments, I got it working. Before, I was too boggled to crack it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seriously folks. I got it working ;)

```js
var width = 300;
var height = 70;

$('iframe#WidgetContent').width(width);
$('iframe#WidgetContent').height(height);

// Get the value of the input width box
$('form #WidgetConfigurator_width').change(function() {

  width = parseInt($(this).val());

  if (width < 180) {
    width = 180;
  }

  if (width > 500) {
    width = 500;
  }

  $('iframe#WidgetContent').width(width);

  getEmbeddableCode();
});


// Get the value of the input width box
$('form #WidgetConfigurator_height').change(function() {

  height = parseInt($(this).val());

  if (height < 70) {
    height = 70;
  }

  $('iframe#WidgetContent').height(height);

  getEmbeddableCode();
});

window.getEmbeddableCode = function() {
  var iframe = $('iframe#WidgetContent');
  var host = $(location).attr('protocol') + '//' + $(location).attr('hostname');

  var code = '<iframe id="WidgetContent" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/widget/1/" frameborder="0" height="' + height + '" width="' + width + '"></iframe>';

  $('#getEmbeddableCode').html(code);

};

if ('' === $('#getEmbeddableCode').val()) {
  getEmbeddableCode();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="WidgetConfigurator" method="post" id="WidgetConfigurator">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="WidgetConfigurator_width">Width widget</label>
    <input type="text" id="WidgetConfigurator_width" name="WidgetConfigurator[width]" class="form-control" placeholder="Da un minimo 180 a un massimo di 500">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="WidgetConfigurator_height">Height widget</label>
    <input type="text" id="WidgetConfigurator_height" name="WidgetConfigurator[height]" class="form-control" placeholder="Minimo 70">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="getEmbeddableCode">Clicca e il codice si copierà automaticamente</label>
    <textarea id="getEmbeddableCode" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>

<iframe id="WidgetContent" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/widget/1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```